# How to identify particular component from tablerow

Tags: android

For EditText I have hard coded as mention code below but how can I check for Button, Spinner and other component...

```
for(int i=0; i< tbl.getChildCount(); i ++) {
    LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout)tbl.getChildAt(i);
    TableRow tbr =(TableRow)ll.getChildAt(0);

    EditText edttxt = (EditText)tbr.getChildAt(1);
}
```

Comment: Please post details of your layout so that we can see the other components that you're trying to find.

Comment: Actually the component should be dynamically created so, there is no proper structure of layout.. Only things I need to know is that.. how to distinguish between different component.

Answer (score 2):

Object x = tbr.getChildAt(1);

if( x  instanceof android.widget.EditText)

{

EditText edttxt = (EditText)tbr.getChildAt(1);

}

Answer (score 0):

When creating the components, call `setId( someUniqueInt )` on each. You can then get a handle to them by calling `tbl.findViewById( someUniqueInt );`.

Alternatively, simply keep a reference to each control after you create it and then there's no need to look it up each time.